# How to improve posted questions math vocabulary?

Tags: discussion

I am not very strong with math vocabulary and I am currently struggling with posing good questions. I have two questions posted here

[How to improve the isometric immersion of a $n$ dimension conformal metric of one variable conformal factor to be less than $2n-1$ dimensions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/857306/how-to-improve-the-isometric-immersion-of-a-n-dimension-conformal-metric-of-on)

and here

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/857292/is-there-a-class-of-second-order-homogeneous-differential-equation-with-a-finite#

and I need some help implementing the correct vocabulary.

One issue I discovered was phrasing "one variable conformal factor", relating to $\omega(x_n)(dx_1^2+dx_2^2+\cdots+dx_n^2)$. I am not even sure if that represents a specific class of problems in Riemann geometer.

Comment: There are two ways I can read your question: (1) I didn't get much feedback - maybe it's my formulations?, or (2) how to improve math vocabulary. As to (1), your writing is just fine - if you got no answers, then this is probably simply because no one knew an answer (or an expert in the field didn't notice your question). As to (2), 2 ideas are to click a tag of interest and read answers by very high rep users (you'll notice soon some have phenomenal English), or to start reading text books in English. After a while, this becomes 2nd nature (I'm no native speaker myself).

Answer (score 1):

As a *general* answer (not one relating necessarily to the questions to which you've referred):

If I am writing a question and do not know how to phrase a particular passage, I:

1. Look in my textbook to see if it refers to something similar.  I might be able to copy the wording.
2. Look at the "suggested duplicates" and "related questions" on the "Ask new question" page.  It is possible they may refer to something similar.
3. As a last resort, I would go ahead and post the question.  Then, I might wonder over to the Chatroom; if I see someone I know (meaning, I've had a conversation in the past with them), I may ask (*politely*) if they know of a better way of phrasing a particular part of the question.

To generalize further at the risk of going off-topic: The above is representative of (what I believe to be) a good question-asking process.  First, see if you can discover the answer yourself from your "given" resources (e.g. from textbooks).  Second, see if you can discover the answer from other inanimate resources (e.g. from other textbooks and/or websites).  Finally, as a last resort, ask a person for help.  I say "as a last resort" because I don't want to waste anyone's time if I could figure out the answer myself.